# Frame Won't Show?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I broke my code, but I cannot figure out how. At all.

At one point, compiling and running the code rendered a window every single time. Then I worked for about 15 minutes, and the frames no longer appear upon running. I've tried undoing the work, adding run methods, adding a main method, and even copying and pasting code directly from my textbook. Nothing has worked.

I tried to paste as little code as possible. Forgive me if my code is sloppy; this is my first time working with swing. Thanks!

```
public class LibraryFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JScrollPane studentScroller = new JScrollPane();
    private JPanel addStudent = new JPanel();
    private JTextField UID   = new JTextField();
    private JTextField name  = new JTextField();
    private JTextField email = new JTextField();
    private JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    private JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
    private JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();

    public LibraryFrame() 
    {

        setTitle("Student Enrollment");
        setSize(500,200);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);


        addStudent.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
        addStudent.add(new JLabel("Enter Student UID:"));
        addStudent.add(UID);
        addStudent.add(new JLabel("Enter Student Name:"));
        addStudent.add(name);
        addStudent.add(new JLabel("Enter Student Email:"));
        addStudent.add(email);
        addStudent.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        addStudent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        okButton.setActionCommand(null);
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //implement window close only
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            { dispose(); }
        });

        buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 10, 10));
        buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 0)));
        buttonPane.add(okButton);
        buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,  0)));
        buttonPane.add(closeButton);

        Container studentPane = getContentPane();
        studentPane.add(addStudent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        studentPane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You show no main method, so we don't know how you try to run this.
- You add all to studentPane. Where do you add studentPane to the JFrame, to the `this` object? If it's not added to the GUI, it will not show.

Comment: I haven't built a main method, yet it ran fine without one from the time I created the set block at the beginning.

Comment: @rice2007: sorry but that makes little sense as nothing will run without a main method, either explicit or implicit (i.e., an applet). Do things right -- create a main method to create your GUI object in. But also you're not showing us the whole class. Could there be a main method that you had but now lost?

Comment: I know that even if I paid you $10,000, you are never going to be believe that it ran without a main method. I also thought it was weird, but I figured it was due to something I had not yet learned. 

I created a new `LibraryFrame` object in another UI class' main method. Perhaps I had been coding for too long last night, and overlooked something small.

BTW, what are you to in your answer when you said `this`?

Comment: Are you asking what `this` is? It refers to the current object. E.g. `this.getMethod()`

Comment: @rice2007 What he means is that you never add `addStudent` to the `JFrame` itself. You need to call `this.add(addStudent);`. Also like it's already been said, it's impossible to run a program if it doesn't contain any `main` method.